# How to populate Excel Spreadsheet with MySQL Data using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Let's go ahead and get this out of the way - i realize I can generate tables with php and mysql and output in 'almost' any format I need but in this scenario, the excel spreadsheet is formatted in some strange ways (layout, color, etc) and the client won't budge. I have to use the exact excel spreadsheet.

I am trying to pull data from a mysql database with php calculations behind it and populate various cells within an Excel file. Is it possible to do this?

Thank you ahead of time

Comment: What version of Excel? That is going to be important

Comment: Start by looking at PHP libraries capable of writing Excel files... you have googled for PHP and Excel haven't you?

Comment: load data outfile to csv, and open the csv in Excel...

Comment: I am not looking to write an excel file. As I mention, I want to open an existing file, add data to it, and save it all with PHP

Comment: I currently run excel 2003 here at the office - .xls files only

Comment: @JM4 - If you'd googled, you should have found PHPExcel (mentioned in Wade's answer) that can read and write both flavours of Excel files (xls and xlsx)

Comment: @OMG Ponies - cannot open csv data, i am ONLY looking to populate an existing excel file - not create a new one in any way.

Comment: @Mark - you are correct, if I googled every possible search term on the planet involving xls, excel, microsoft, php, mysql I might have found the answer in three seconds. My question is posted here to get clarification from a network of trusted individuals who might provide insight into what is "good", what works, and what is crap. You ask me for a recommendation on what is good to eat in New York and I tell you to Google it for the answer is absurd. Note: "populate excel spreadsheet php" and "write to existing .xls php" do not talk about the software at all.

Comment: I am trying to do the exact same thing. I have to populate regular fields and drop-down fields in an Excel 2003 spreadsheet that has some macros. I am guessing that this is impossible, but I figured I would add on to this question. Thanks for any help anyone has!

Comment: Appears related to [12129976](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129976)

Comment: @arober11 - your point? This question was asked almost 2 years ago compared to the recent question you just referenced.

Comment: Cut-n-paste failure, meant to add the comment to the other post, but at least the to are now linked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try PHPExcel ( http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for the link. I came across this link before (and i should have added to my intial question) but we run Excel 2003 so the XML from 2007 does not apply (I think).

Comment: MS Excel 2003 reads/writes BIFF8 xls files as its default format... This is the Exce5 Reader/Writer in PHPExcel