# I need to retrieve rows in database then email that list

Tags: php, mysql, email

How can I retrieve rows from database then use a `mail()` function to then email that list in my php file.

The query that I am using which this works:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE date_stamp BETWEEN '$currentdate' - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND '$currentdate'";`
```

But the problem I am having is listing out all the data to then email, I am only getting the one result from database, but not all the rows. I know its the way my loop is setup, that is what I am needing help with.

Below is the full code minus the database connect.

```
$to = 'email@email.com';

// email subject     
$subject = 'Email leads beginning '.$newdate." through ".$currentdate;

// Construct email body     
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$recipients = array();
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $content = $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."<br>";
        }
            };

$body_message = $content;

// email headers     
$headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";  

mail($to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
```

Comment: not clear what part of this your asking about

Comment: I cant list out all the rows for $body_message.

Comment: If your while loop, why are you looping through $result?

Comment: instead of `$content = ` use `$content .=` or `$content = $content .`

Comment: Wow, that worked, something so small. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that

```
$to = 'email@email.com';

// email subject     
$subject = 'Email leads beginning '.$newdate." through ".$currentdate;

// Construct email body     
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$recipients = array();
$body_message = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $body_message .= $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."<br>";
}

// email headers     
$headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";  

mail($to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
```

Comment: That didnt seem to work, but I was able to get it working with a simple change of my $content to $content .=

Comment: Do you recommend your change or what I did?

Comment: There's some strange things in your code, like `$body_message = $content;` why do you do that when you can use only one variable? Or the semicolon after the the curly brace `};`

Comment: The semicolon was a typo. I actually replaced my code with your edit and that seems to work just fine.

Comment: Furthermore, why you used the `foreach` with the `$results` inside the `while` cycle when you already have the `$row`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just used the general loop I have for something else I am using. But I changed it to your code and it is working great.

Comment: Real quick if I wanted to take that same list and attach it in a spreadsheet, how would you recommend I do that?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741416/how-to-populate-excel-spreadsheet-with-mysql-data-using-php AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail